# How to set up ready state for Franka?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I am new to here. I am trying to use Franka panda arm. There was a python file for "move to start" in franka ros(see
[link text](https://github.com/frankaemika/franka_ros/blob/kinetic-devel/franka_example_controllers/scripts/move_to_start.py))
But I want to make it come true by c++. Do I neet to set up every joint pose? How to set up it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309868/how-to-set-up-ready-state-for-franka?/) by [Rachel](https://answers.ros.org/users/38658/rachel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-12-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many ways: the one I decided to start with was by using the moveit library and [their tutorials](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/move_group_interface/move_group_interface_tutorial.html). In particular, at first I created a simple node with just a snippet from the whole [tutorial code](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_tutorials/blob/kinetic-devel/doc/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface_tutorial.cpp).

You want to move to a joint space configuration (not to a cartesian pose like in the tutorial) so the pose is stored in a vector:

```
auto panda_home_pose = std::vector<double> {  0.00
                                           , -0.25 * pi
                                           ,  0.00
                                           , -0.75 * pi
                                           ,  0.00
                                           ,  0.50 * pi
                                           ,  0.25 * pi };
```

and you will want to use [setJointValueTarget](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroupInterface.html#a71e3819bd31711dcb81c18305ca9a521) instead of setPoseTarget like the tutorial does. I recommend also setting very slow velocities and accelerations at first, even more so because of potential reflex errors from the robot due to high jerk and whatnot. For this use setMaxVelocityScalingFactor and setMaxAccelerationScalingFactor. After these you can call plan and execute separately or together as you see fit, but the tutorial seems clear in that regard.

---

Originally posted by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) with karma: 589 on 2018-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0